# Why can't I pass a value to a User Control?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

This is my code:

```
<myOwnCtrls:SocialLabel ID="SocialLabel1" CustomName="<%=CurrentPage.Titolo %>" runat="server" />
```

but on `SocialLabel1`, if I write the content of `CustomName`, it prints `<%=CurrentPage.Titolo %>`, not the content of `CurrentPage.Titolo`.

Why? And how can I do it without passing between the code behind?

Comment: What is `CurrentPage` and what is `Titolo`?

Comment: I mean `CurrentPage` - is it the name of the class? And `Titolo` - is it a property of this class? Is it static? Actually it might be helpful to post the declaration of `Titolo`.

Comment: CurrentPage is a class created when I have inserted that control. Titolo is a property of that class.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in plain html controls but not in user controls. You have to assign CustomName in code behind:

```
SocialLabel1.CustomName = CurrentPage.Titolo;
```

Comment: I mean that I just passing a string. Maybe you are thinking an object.

Comment: Wrong. Code behind isn't necessary, and he's said he wants to avoid that. The principle of what he's trying to achieve is correct, you can definitely do this with user controls, it'll be a simple syntax issue no doubt.

Comment: @DeeMac No it's not a syntax issue I've struggled with this before.

Comment: So you're implying that it's impossible to assign a member of a user control a value with inline code and that it's only possible with html controls? That's massively incorrect. I do this extensively inside repeater templates, you can rest assured it's very possible.

Comment: @markzzz Type of the user control property you are trying to assign doesn't metter. You can't user server-side code blocks inside user controls.

Comment: @DeeMac What you do extensively is data-binding <%#Bind... yes that's possible.

Comment: I have code in front of me now that I have working without a problem: `<CMU:AuthorDisplayControl runat="server" Author='<%# Article.Author %>'></CMU:AuthorDisplayControl>` Here I've used a server-side code block inside my user control, just as you said I couldn't.

Comment: @DeeMac Try it with a new empty page and control (without data binding). Please take a look at these links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: The page is, up to now, an empty page. The code I have posted above is outside of any repeater or other control. The `Article` I'm referring to is declared on the page. Not that that matters, as long as that particular part of code has access to that object I can assign it to a publicly accessible member of any server-side control in-line.

Comment: It's very weird because when I test it with <%= the exact string is assigned not the value (as OP said), and when I change it to <%# nothing happens (without any errors).